# How do I make aiohttp post photo request in python?

Tags: python, post, beautifulsoup, python-requests, aiohttp

**I am trying to upload a file to the site, but without success. I need to get the uuid of the file to create a post on vinted.hu. There is no problem with cookies and headers, only with the request :'(**

**any help needed!**

**file accept button**

```
<input data_testid="add-photos-input" name="photos" class="u-hidden" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="">
```

**piece code to send a photo**

```
with open('data/post/213.jpg', 'rb') as file:
    async with session.post('https://www.vinted.hu/api/v2/photos',headers=headers, data={"photos": file}) as response:
        print(await response.text())
```

**Result**

```
{"code":99,"message":"Sorry, there are some errors","message_code":"validation_error","errors":[{"field":"base","value":"param is missing or the value is empty: photo\nDid you mean?  photos"}],"payload":{}}
```

**piece code1 to send a photo**

```
data = FormData()
data.add_field('photos',open('data/post/213.jpg', 'rb'), filename='213.jpg', content_type='image/*')
async with session.post('https://www.vinted.hu/api/v2/photos',headers=headers, data=data) as response:
    print(await response.text())
```

**Result1**

```
{"code":99,"message":"Sorry, there are some errors","message_code":"validation_error","errors":[{"field":"base","value":"param is missing or the value is empty: photo\nDid you mean?  photos"}],"payload":{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `multipart/form-data` content type in the request payload. like the code below

```
import aiohttp

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    headers = {...}  # your headers here
    data = aiohttp.FormData()
    with open('data/post/213.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        data.add_field('photos', f, filename='213.jpg', content_type='image/jpeg')
    async with session.post('https://www.vinted.hu/api/v2/photos', headers=headers, data=data) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            data = await response.json()
            # do something with the response
        else:
            # handle the error
```

Comment: error 401, {"code":99,"message":"Sorry, there are some errors","message_code":"validation_error","errors":[{"field":"base","value":"param is missing or the value is empty: photo\nDid you mean?  photos"}],"payload":{}}